# Where does O365 track end user clicks on SafeLinks?

Tags: email, microsoft-office-365, malware

O365 SafeLinks policy has a setting to disable the per-user clicks of URLs in an email message.

I want to obtain a report of potentially infected desktops where the user clicked on the URL and either had malware installed or was phished for information.

Where can I obtain a report of the per-user clicks for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

If tracking URLs is enabled, this information can be found in the Exchange
Admin Center by choosing mail flow > URL trace. You can sort the URL Trace report by date range,
recipients, and specific URLs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyg1m.png)

Source:https://o365ppsecurity.blob.core.windows.net/assets/ATP%20Product%20Guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can view the reports in the [Advanced Threat Protection Dashboard](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-reports-for-office-365-advanced-threat-protection-e47e838c-d99e-4c0b-b9aa-e66c4fae902f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)